# other arguments for complex_ode

Tags: python, scipy, ode

Im trying to solve a big system of coupled first order ODEs, so I tried to use complex_ode as follows

```
bigstep = complex_ode(evol, jac=None)
t0=0
bigstep.set_initial_value(inivec, t0).set_f_params(DEST_TWO_DTs,TWO_DTs_Hamil,bigtwoside,kappa)
t1 = 10
dt = 0.1
while bigstep.successful() and bigstep.t < t1:
     print(bigstep.t+dt, bigstep.integrate(bigstep.t+dt))
```

and get this error

```
--> 631         f = self.cf(*((t, y[::2] + 1j * y[1::2]) + f_args))
    632         # self.tmp is a real-valued array containing the interleaved
    633         # real and imaginary parts of f.

    TypeError: evol() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'adest', 'hamii', 'bigside', and 'kappa'
```

But i don´t get why I get this, since my evol function is defined as

```
def evol(t,vecrho,adest,hamii,bigside,kappa):
  matrho=vec_to_mat(vecrho,bigside)
  ham_t=hamii/hmeVps+TWO_pump(t)*(adest+adest.T)/hmeVps
  matevo=mastereq(matrho,ham_t,adest,kappa/hmeVps)
  return mat_to_vec(matevo)
```

And I used .set_f_params(DEST_TWO_DTs,TWO_DTs_Hamil,bigtwoside,kappa)